# Using Gnuplot to make a 3D surface chart

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, coordinates

I have just started to use Gnuplot to make 3D surface charts using the data calculated by my programs.  I wonder if it is possible to read the X, Y, and Z coordinates from the chart on the screen interactively by placing a mouse pointer on the location of interest?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hypertext is an option. Check `help hypertext`. However, if you have a 3D surface with thousands of data points, I'm not sure if hypertext is the best idea. It probably depends on your data. Check the example below.

**Code:**

```
### hypertext in 3D
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
do for [i=1:20] {
    print sprintf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", rand(0), rand(0), rand(0))
}
set print

myCoordinates(x,y,z) = sprintf("%g, %g, %g", x,y,z)
myRandomColor(n) = int(rand(0)*0xffffff)

splot $Data u 1:2:3:(myCoordinates($1,$2,$3)):(myRandomColor(0)) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screen capture of wxt terminal)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, wanted to try.  But got a warning "No previous file name" after executing splot command.  What do I miss?  LIke I said, I am new to gnuplot.

Comment: I found my mistake.  Here is a command that works fine.  Thank you.                          
 splot $Data u 1:2:3:(myCoordinates($1,$2,$3)):(myRandomColor(0)) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb var notitle

Comment: ah, sorry, for the mistake. In an earlier version I had two plot commands and removed one. I will correct it.

Comment: so, does it answer your question?

Comment: It does to a great degree, thank you much.  Though not completely.  I have to figure out how apply your method (hypertext) to a surface created with pm3d command.  My 3D surface is a "heatmap" colored with RGB palette.  I will try today and give you a feedback.  I wonder if hypertext can be used with pm3d surface at all?